# how to check if json string contains multiple root elements in java?

Tags: json, jackson, gson

below i have a malformed json, it has multiple root elements and it should not behave like the way it is, currently im using jackson to do the reading, however instead of showing an exception, jackson seems to ignore everything after the first valid json array, here is a link with them saying [this is working as designed](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/726), so in this case, whats the easiest way to catch this scenario when there are multiple root elements?

and in general, which library would be the best when it comes to validate json string?

```
[
   {
      "age":"12",
      "name":"albert"
   },
   {
      "age":"15",
      "name":"bob"
   }
]
{
      "age":"20",
      "name":"charlie"
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are no "multiple root elements" in JSON. If that's the case for your string, you don't have JSON anymore, but something else - a superset, which follows rules that have not been defined in the JSON spec. And either you don't go outside the spec, or you define those rules yourself, for your use case, or you use a definition that someone else has come up with (such as *"multiple JSON entities per file, but only one per line"*). It's your call. But a regular, spec-compliant parser will not help you.

Comment: (PS: As for Jackson, they apparently decided to stop parsing gracefully when the closing `}` or `]` is reached, as opposed to throwing an error, *maybe* to give you a means to easily adapt the parser to input that is not covered by the spec. Not every parser does that, others will simply blow up, such as the one in JavaScript or Python, which is an equally justified design decision.)